# TTL elastic search not working

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, ttl, logstash

I need to put a TTL with each of the logs exported from logstash.

I have already created a folder 'mappings' under the config folder, under which I have a folder _default, under which I have the json file *default*.json, which has:

```
{
    "_default_" : {
        "_ttl" : { "enabled" : true, "default" : "10s" }
    }
}
```

I am exporting my logs to elastic server with logstash. THe config file is:

```
input {
stdin {
    type => "stdin-type"
  }
}
filter {

  grok {
    type => "stdin-type"
    pattern => "I am %{USERNAME:username}"
add_tag=>"{username}"
  }

}
output {
  stdout { debug => true debug_format => "json"}
  elasticsearch
{
}
}
```

I should expect that the logs get deleted from ELastic Search after 10 seconds, but that is not the case. The logs persist.
Where am I going wrong? I am totally stuck.

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Fine guys, got it to work. Simply had to change

```
MESSAGE %{DATA}ERR_SYSTEM%{DATA}
```

to

```
MESSAGE %{DATA}ERR_SYSTEM.*
```

Answer (score 0):

use templates:

`{
    "template_1" :
    {
        "template" : "logstash-*",
        "settings" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 5,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1,
            "index.cache.field.type" : "soft",
            "index.refresh_interval" : "5s",
            "index.store.compress.stored" : true,
            "index" : {
                "store" : { "compress" : { "stored" : true }}
            }
        },
        "mappings" : {
            "nginxlog" : {
               "_ttl" : {"enabled" : true, "default" : "1m"},
               "properties" : {
                  "@timestamp": { "type": "date", "format" : "dateOptionalTime"}
               }
            }
        }
    }
}`

set 1 minute,automatically delete a minute later